# Athena Unload TEXTFILE with null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am currently utilizing the `UNLOAD` feature in AWS Athena, where I query something like:

```
UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM sometable) TO 's3://<location>' WITH (format = 'TEXTFILE', field_delimeter = ',')
```

This generates a bunch of `.gz` files.  My issue is that all the `null/empty` values have been converted to `\N`.  Is there a way to replace this with just an empty string?

I did notice that if I just do `SELECT * FROM sometable`, basically not using unload, it seems to be what I want (without `\N`).  I would like to get similar results with the unload, if its possible.  There seems to be a `SERDEPROPERTIES` with `serialization.null.format` (for creating a table), but not sure how to use it with unload.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pass this property as per documentation. Have you tried coalesce or NULLIF instead to replace null values so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Do I do that per column?

Comment: yes in the select query. You need to add it for all the columns that has null values